# Xamarin-Get near by location

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I found the code to get the latitude and longitudes of the location. Now, I want to find a near by location. Like find a restaurant nearby.

So, If i search subway, i should get the co-ordinates of the near by subway.

To find the location I used this code :

```
 var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
            locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;
            var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 10000);
```

But How can I get the near by location ?
I want in Xamarin Forms.

Answer (score 1):

> But How can I get the near by location ? I want in Xamarin Forms.

I guess you followed the official document [Adding a Map in Xamarin.Forms](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/) to build your app, but the [APIs for Map](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/Xamarin.Forms.Maps/) of Xamarin Forms is only for Displaying and Annotating Maps.

For Android platform, the map service used in the guide is [Google Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/), to find a nearby location, we need to use [Places API for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/), and there is no API of Xamarin Forms to do this job. Since Xamarin.Forms is a cross-platform UI toolkit that allows developers to create native user interface layouts shared across platforms, then we need to use [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/) to call into platform-specific functionality from PCL.

For iOS platform, I'm not familiar with iOS development, but I think the map of Xamarin Forms toolkit uses the map of native iOS, to my knowledge, the map service of iOS native map depends on the region where users are. But you can follow iOS's official document [About Location Services and Maps](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) to find a nearby place. Also, we need to use `DependencyService` to call iOS platform APIs from PCL.

Anyway, there is no easy way to call a API from PCL to find a place for now, we need to implement this feature on each platform.

Answer (score 1):

To find the nearby locations one can use The `Google Places API Web Service` in `Xamarin forms`. Using this `api` the google places data can be retrieved from google servers. The places data includes information about restaurants, lodges, hospitals, health centers and many more. The sample is this:

```
 public async Task<List<Place>> GetNearByPlacesAsync()
    {
 RootObject rootObject=null;
        client = new HttpClient();
        CultureInfo In = new CultureInfo("en-IN");
        string latitude = position.Latitude.ToString(In);
        string longitude = position.Longitude.ToString(In);
        string restUrl = $"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="+latitude+","+longitude+"&radius=1000&type="+search+"&key=your API";
        var uri = new Uri(restUrl);           
            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);
        }
        else
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("No web response", "Unable to retrieve information, please try again", "OK");
        }

            return rootObject.results;
    }
```

This root object have all the information asked in the web request. Now you can show the nearby location via `pins` like this:

```
private async void AddPins()
    {
        try
        {
            var Places = await GetNearByPlacesAsync();
            if (Places.Count == 0|| Places==null)
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("No Places found", "No Places found for this location", "OK");
            else
            { 
            map.Pins.Clear();
       foreach(Place place in Places)
            {

                map.Pins.Add(new Pin()
                {
                    BindingContext = place,
                    Tag = place,
                    Label = place.name,
                    Position = new Position(place.geometry.location.lat, place.geometry.location.lng),
                });
            }
       }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"                 ERROR{0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The `map` is the name of `Map Element` in UI.